# What is the correct way to process REST requests in Contoller

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have created a controller for an "applications" table. The web and REST interfaces are working but I think the add and edit functions should be better.

When I tested add and edit I found the data needed to be posted in web FORM format (not JSON).

I found I needed to use "$this->request->input('json_decode')" in the save to decode the JSON data.  I thought this happened automagically.

This function now works for add (edit is similar) and displays my json/add.ctp so I can return the successful record to the user.

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Application->create();

        //Is the request REST passing a JSON object?
        if (preg_match('/\.json/', $this->request->here)){
            //This is a REST call
            $this->set('status', $this->Application->save($this->request->input('json_decode')));
        } else {
            //This is an interactive session
            if ($this->Application->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The application has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The application could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the "$this->request->here" to see if it ends in ".json". Is this the "correct" way to process the REST call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire section in the CakePHP Book for this.  I think it will answer your question(s):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Comment: I have read that and implemented it but it didn't seem to decode the JSON post data. I had to identify it was a JSON request and decode the data.  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I needed to add "$this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));" to my function and then the magic happened.  It is in the RequestHandler doco.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, does your action accept JSON data & Form Data? or just JSON data?

The .json is purely for the output of your data, you are able to send JSON data with the .xml extension, the difference being once the data is sterilised, it will output in XML.

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if(empty($this->request->data)){
            $data = $this->request->input('json_decode', TRUE);
        } else {
            $data = $this->request->data;
        }
} else {
        $data = $this->params['url'];
}
```

Above is kind of what you should be doing, check if the data comes from a form, if not, decode JSON, and if it is NOT a POST, save parameters that have been included into the URL.

I am not saying the above is the "right" way to do it, but thats probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I think that is a better way to do it. I will give it a try.

Comment: I think this is the code I was missing.  I added "$this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));" to my function and then the JSON data was decoded in $this->request->data which is what it says in the doco.